# namespace in java dom issue

Tags: java, xml, dom

I'm using the following API's to create Dom document with namespace
and my question is why I need to put the first argument "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/"
does it some kind of  constant ?
when I put null I get error . I ask it since it too generic so why I should put it ?

```
rootTreeNode.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/" ,"xmlns:m", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata");
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to deal with namespace:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws Throwable {
   DocumentBuilderFactory dbf  = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
   dbf.setNamespaceAware( true );

   DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
   Document doc = db.newDocument();

   Element root = doc.createElement( "root" );
   root.setAttribute( "xmlns:m" , "http://www.lfinance.fr/blog-rachat-credits" );
   root.setAttribute( "xmlns:rt", "http://www.lfinance.fr/forum-rachat-credits" );
   doc.appendChild( root );

   Element elt = doc.createElement( "simple" );
   elt.setAttribute( "m:FC_TargetPath"   , "false" );
   elt.setAttribute( "m:FC_KeepInContent", "false" );
   elt.setAttribute( "rt:filterable"     , "false" );

   root.appendChild( doc.createTextNode( "\n\t" ));
   root.appendChild( elt );
   root.appendChild( doc.createTextNode( "\n" ));
   TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(
      new DOMSource( doc ),
      new StreamResult( System.out ));
}
```

Comment: HI Aubin, you already post this solution in previous post,the document is OK but I post here generic question...                                                           Thanks anyway